# How can I solve this "UserWarning: Attempting to use a closed FileWriter " error when trying to train my object detection model

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-recognition

I have made an object detection model which trained perfectly but now I removed some images from the training set to add newer better images and I'm getting the following errors

```
C:\Users\Swayam\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\summary\writer\writer.py:386: UserWarning: 
Attempting to use a closed FileWriter. The operation will be a noop 
unless 
the FileWriter is explicitly reopened.
warnings.warn("Attempting to use a closed FileWriter. "
```

The following code is already present to reopen the FileWriter:

```
 def reopen(self):
     self.event_writer.reopen()
     self._closed = False
```

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of steps in the training which was 200000 was reached and so it could not train further. 
Need to change the limit in the python file

Comment: @sworn bhai Which python file do you mean? And what would be changed? I got the same issue.